# command not found when adding sudo before my command

Tags: linux, binary, operating-system, gitlab

I'am using gitlab-runner binary and I cannot launch commands needed privilege.
I'am logged with my user sysadmin
I have put the binary in /usr/local/bin and i did'nt need to add the path in my PATH variable.
Here my bash_profile

```
# User specific environment and startup programs

PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin

export PATH

echo $PATH

/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/home/sysadmin/bin
```

Command without sudo work's perfectly

```
gitlab-runner -help
NAME:
   gitlab-runner - a GitLab Runner

USAGE:
   gitlab-runner [global options] command [command options] [arguments...]
```

But all command with sudo return

```
sudo gitlab-runner status
```

return

```
command not found
```

NOW FOR ROOT

This is my bash_profile for root.

```
  # User specific environment and startup programs
    GITLAB_RUNNER=/usr/local/bin
    PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin:$GITLAB_RUNNER

    export PATH
    export GITLAB_RUNNER

echo $PATH

/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/root/bin:/usr/local/bin

gitlab-runner status
gitlab-runner: Service is running!
```

The only way to use any command it's to use the path where the binary is located.

```
[sysadmin@XXXXXXXX ~]$ sudo /usr/local/bin/gitlab-runner status
Runtime platform                                    arch=amd64 os=linux pid=12666 revision=8bb608ff version=11.7.0
gitlab-runner: Service is running!
```

Please can you explain me what's going wrong.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

When you use sudo, you are running the command as root user/super user. The root user doesn't have `/usr/local/bin/` in PATH variable in your case. That is why you are able to run the command using full path. If you want to verify this, you can try the following

`sudo -E env "PATH=$PATH" gitlab-runner status`

This will use the PATH variable of the current user.